# I'm trying to find Vth, somehow my Vx gets cancelled out but my Vth is wrong

Tags: thevenin

I'm trying to find out how to solve for the Thevenin equivalent. I tried to use a 1A test source, but it didn't seem to work. Anyone can help please? Much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the calculation for Rth using test source method.Vth you can try

yourself .Please let me know if you need any support for calculating Vth.

[image]

Comment: I think I understand this method, thanks for the help.

Comment: if that solves your problem you can accept the answer  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I would connect a voltage source to the output and use Vout = 0 and Vout = 60 to simplify the problem.

You'll get Iout = -20A and Iout = -14A, so the output resistance is 10Ω and the open-circuit voltage then must be 200V.

Comment: Okay, I'll test it out. Thanks for the help!